# Typescript inference error - variable with type string changes to undefined inside for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using await-to-js library for error handling (the `to` method in the example below comes from the library)

For some reason, the type of a variable changes to `string | undefined` inside of a `for..of` loop, when the value of the same variable is `string` outside of the loop.

Consider the following example (see `testMethod` for error):

```js
function to<T, U = Error>(
    promise: Promise<T>,
    errorExt?: object
): Promise<[U, undefined] | [null, T]> {
    return promise
        .then<[null, T]>((data: T) => [null, data])
        .catch<[U, undefined]>((err: U) => {
            if (errorExt) {
                const parsedError = Object.assign({}, err, errorExt);
                return [parsedError, undefined];
            }

            return [err, undefined];
        });
}


async function retrieveAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
    const randomNumber = Math.random();

    if(randomNumber < 0.5) {
        throw new Error("Failed");
    }

    return "testToken";
}

    
function printAccessToken(accessToken: string) {
    console.log(accessToken);
};

async function testMethod(): Promise<boolean> {
    const accessTokenPromise = retrieveAccessToken();

    const [err, accessToken] = await to(accessTokenPromise);

    if(err){
        console.log("Failed");
        return false;
    }

    // No error here
    printAccessToken(accessToken);

    for(let i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
        // Error! Type Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to 
        // parameter of type 'string'.
        printAccessToken(accessToken);
    }

    return true;
}
```

This seems to be solved by adding a if check on accessToken e.g. `if(!accessToken)` however it doesn't make sense why the type of `accessToken` is `string | undefined` inside of the for loop but `string` outside of it?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhggPAFQDTIKrIC8yAogE5kJkB8AFMAJAAOlAtnAM4CmAXMgAptOXLNWyMuFKiQAeMAPx8EAIwBWXWMACUfQQnbd0AbTy5IAEy4g4ELuYC6yAD7IjEMABsPuTPerIAb0YyLhgwMhQWfWFGBgA6GAALLghjdy8fP1pacwBDGFy+TC0ifzdPb2Q8gvstWLiofKhE41NkCysbOyzaSTI+PBLCfyCGMbgQZF6pMlkYEtGxhigkDhhkJlyybnNySjIiZAB5NQ0YONyODjgAcwhaAIBfXD6XmbmtAG5YsZCwiNcm22dj2VDMEEs1lsDm+S0ewB+f3CKCMr3aEM60PssIYjy+wHhCMuAE9oMhwNB4EhkH8yHAuAA3LgAQSgUC4V0wCAA1ilaDoBEJDGs6RAbiNgMgpcgVhA1jTchD9AA5MCsZSSQ4AWXyiTiZEV5n0-O+jAmtANStYqvVmvQyAADHEAKwLWJJSgAd2Qtm9oLItAARAAxXJwDx2QP43EIhhIgGBmAcmBc3kQQPfQnS5CgSCwRCRUUwVnszk8vm5NkcjiplJ8EU2G5u7OyjgICNxDwIG60SulmvliD4x6mklkin56lJtZa0KJBDmfm6IUiZQIdtcRUSlurdZ96u1iB6AxcQ60+lMksHwcmhE7uXrVEUXD7stpxzEXKesPrNC9qtvikx7CPikrSuafRaIsrYbp23ZBqG4aRvi2bZvGKAgLkHjcN82aEgwAD0BHIMqCDIH0VDIMkISMCwNjFgBA5pv+-aHqBDAgFQtARuscCHA6yCfMgfH2s6QlwAA1BJUGxERpAzAAhMgmDEkwp7MmQNxqik6wIJMMCqaeADkDZis46KQl05hGcJHA+gge5XLcEC5MoEaoGRYGocgclArkrChJqemoIZyAmTAoo3EZcRecgzBFlegH3K+TEpNG+HoagZBgFwmbAEAA)

Comment: Maybe the fact that the function can throw an exception is affecting its type, somehow?

Comment: It is interesting that it only shows the warning/error for the one in the for loop. Being that the retrieveAccessToken() may return a string or nothing one would think both locations would be flagged.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript has issues analyzing types in destructuring syntax. To get the expected behavior, assign the resolved value of `to` to a local variable, and reference `accessToken` *after* checking `err`.

Change:

```
    const [err, accessToken] = await to(accessTokenPromise);

    if(err){
        console.log("Failed");
        return false;
    }
```

Into:

```
    const toResult = await to(accessTokenPromise);

    const [err] = toResult;
    if(err){
        console.log("Failed");
        return false;
    }
    const [, accessToken] = toResult;
```

[**Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhggPAFQDTIKrIC8yAogE5kJkB8AFMAJAAOlAtnAM4CmAXMgAptOXLNWyMuFKiQAeMAPx8EAIwBWXWMACUfQQnbd0AbTy5IAEy4g4ELuYC6yAD7IjEMABsPuTPerIAb0YyLhgwMhQWfWFGBgA6GAALLghjdy8fP1pacwBDGFy+TC0ifzdPb2Q8gvstWLiofKhE41NkCysbOyzaSTI+PBLCfyCGMbgQZF6pMlkYEtGxhigkDhhkJlyybnNySjIiZAB5NQ0YONyODjgAcwhaAIBfXD6XmbmtAG5YsZCwiNcm22dj2VDMEEs1lsDm+S0ewB+f3CKCMr3aEM60PssIYjy+wHhCMuAE9oMhwNB4EhkH8yHAuAA3LgAQSgUC4V0wCAA1ilaDoBEJDGs6RAbiNgMgpcgVhA1jTchD9AA5MCsZSSQ4AWXyiTiZEV5n0-O+jAmtANStYqvVmvQyAADHEAKwLWJJSgAd2Qtm9oLItAARAAxXJwDx2QP43EIhhIgGBmAcmBc3kQQPfQnS5CgSCwRCRUUwVnszk8vm5NkcjiplJ8EU2G5u7OyjgICNxDwIG60SulmvliD4x6mklkin56lJtZa0KJBDmfm6IUiZQIdtcRUSlurdZ96u1iB6AxcQ60+lMksHwcmhE7uXrNAAJQ5nnWxFynrDj4QvarZbTY9hHxSVpVbdZUQoRxiGfV8PBgb5s3NPotEWVsN07bsg1DcNI3xbNs3jFAQFyDxuEQ6V4WWXdXFwfcAJSaDUAQF8ODfU0GAAek45BlQQZA+ioZBkhCRgWBsYt-wHNM-37Q8QIYEAqFoCN1jgQ4HWQT5kHU+1nW0uAAGpDNQ2JuNIGYAEJkEwYkmFPZkyBuNUUnWBBJhgOzTwAcgbMVnHRSEunMbydI4H0ED3K5bggXJlAjZicwI6VzKBXJWFCTV3NQLzkF8mBRRuby4lAqVmCLK8GPuejpJSaNCTjUJkVQMgwC4TNgCAA)